# Overlapping of Time Slot

Tags: php, mysql

I'm developing "Meeting Room" project where the user selects the time slot to book the room.For the insert process i have query written but with that i have written the query to check for overlapping of time slot. It works fine for the 1st time but whenever I check next in same session then it gives the message of overlapping of time slot & doesn't allow the data to be inserted.
Here's my **[php](http://www.php.net)** code snippet :-

```
<?php
session_start();
$host="localhost"; // Host name
$username="root"; // Mysql username
$password=""; // Mysql password
$db_name="test"; // Database name

// Connect to server and select databse.
$conn=mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password) or die("cannot connect");

mysqli_select_db($conn,$db_name);
$sname=$_SESSION['usr_name'];


$room = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['txtrname']);
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['txtname']);
$purpose = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['txtpurpose']);
$attendee = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['attendee']);
$date = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['txtdate']);
$btime = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['btime']);
$etime = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['etime']);

$query = "SELECT count(*) as  c from bookingdetails WHERE starttime<='$etime' AND endtime>='$btime' AND date = '$date' AND status_id='2'";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

$overlappings =mysqli_fetch_array($result);

// If there is no overlapping
if($overlappings[0] <= 0) {

    // INSERT QUERY HERE
    $sql="INSERT INTO bookingdetails (room,name,purpose,attendee,date,starttime,endtime,status_id)VALUES('$room','$name','$purpose','$attendee','$date','$btime','$etime','2')";

    if (mysqli_query($conn,$sql))
      {
        //echo "Record added";
        }
    else
    {
        die('Error: ' . mysqli_error());
    }
} else {
    echo 'Time Slot is overlapping.Change the time slot';    
}
?>
```

Comment: Instead of `$overlappings =mysqli_fetch_array($result);

// If there is no overlapping
if($overlappings[0] <= 0)` try `mysql_num_rows($result) == 0` remove the **$overlappings = mysqli_fetch_array($result)** and try this `if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0)`

Comment: You don't really need to do all that checking stuff first. But this has been answered before.

Comment: When you say it doesn't allow you to insert data, what do you mean exactly? Do you get a mysql error, a php error or does everything works but the change isn't visible in the table ?

Comment: It doesn't show in the table.

Comment: Strawberry then what is the solution for it ?